# Rails ActionMailer include CC field without sending CC email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Not sure this is a possibility.

My scenario involves a user submitting a ticket and two emails are sent.

One email is being sent the the Submitter (confirmation), another to the Admin (alert of created ticket).

For the email being sent to the Admin, I'd like to include the Submitters email in the CC field so that they can just reply all and update the Submitter of any information.  Since there is already an email being sent to the Submitter, I don't actually want the Admin email CC'd to the Submitter, of course.

Does anyone know if it's possible with Rails to add the CC field in the header of the message without actually sending the email to them?

Here is my `newticket.mailer.rb` if that helps:

```
class NewticketMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "TicketTracker@example.org"

def email_subjectConf
  "Facilities Ticket Confirmation - Thank you!"
end  

def email_subjectCreation
  "Facilities Ticket created for your location!"
end  

def ticket_confirmation(ticket)
 @ticket = ticket

mail to: @ticket.submitter.full_email, subject: email_subjectConf
end

def ticket_creation(ticket)
 @ticket = ticket

mail to: @ticket.mailing_list.name, subject: email_subjectCreation
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May by you should use "Reply-To" header in Admin message.

```
mail( :to => @ticket.mailing_list.name,
      :subject => email_subjectCreation,
      :reply-to => @ticket.submitter.full_email )
```

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, I was way overthinking this. I feel very stupid. Thanks